# Azure AKS with Application Gateway: An internal service that is only callable by other services within the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I am using Azure AKS and Application Gateway. (And get new to Kubernetes)

Is it possible to have a deployment/service that can only be called from other services within that cluster? But have a single endpoint exposed to the outside world?

E.g.
I have api end points to CRUD a record used by other services within the cluster and default namespace. None of these should be accessible from external calls.

BUT. There is a single GET request endpoint which is open to the public.

If this is possible where would the config go? In the Kubernetes yaml or some ingress rule i have to manually manage within Azure?

Is there any documentation? I'm not even sure what to search for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BUT. There is a single GET request endpoint which is open to the public.

you can expose a specific path of the application to the external world using `ingress path`, for example, the `GET` path is `api/get/user/profiler`
you can create an ingress like this

[services-networking-ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |2
      location /internal {
        deny all;
        return 403;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/get/user
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.example.com
    secretName: mydomain.example.tls
```

The client will be able to reach all path having prefix like `/api/get/user/profile/88`, but if the path is static you can convert nginx path type to `Exact`

[better-path-matching-with-path-types](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/#better-path-matching-with-path-types)

within cluster, you can simply use `servicename.namespace:service-port/api/getuser/profile` and it should work inside the Kubernetes cluster.